# Ошибка работы скрипта после обновления системы

Tags: php

Привет, пару дней назад на хосте отрубили какой-то функционал. Не работают скрипты такого рода

```
$get = file_get_contents_curl("http://api.bing.net/
$get = file_get_contents ("http://api.bing.net/
```

Как можно это дело починить или исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ya.ru");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($output);
?>
```

Comment: данный скрипт тоже не работает, даже ошибку не выдает (((